# Getting error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've been getting this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined

```
let channel = message.guild.channel.cache.find('830754717108797450')
```

Here's my code:

````
const MinecraftCommand = require('../../contracts/MinecraftCommand')
const Discord = require('discord.js-light');
const { Message } = require('discord.js-light');
const ms = require('pretty-ms');
const client = require ('discord.js-light')

class GuildMemberReportCommand extends MinecraftCommand {
  onCommand(username, message) {
    
let args = this.getArgs(message)
let reason = args[1];

let guild = message.guild.cache.get('')
    
let channel = message.guild.channel.cache.find('830754717108797450')

let reporteduser = args[0];

let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle("Guild Member Report!")
.addField("Reason", reason)
.addField("Reported By", username)
.addField("Reported User", reporteduser)
.setColor("#f49542")
            if (!reason) return this.send('Report reason needs to be specified!', username);
            if (!username) return this.send ('Reported member was not speified!', username);
    this.send(`${username}, $args[0] has been reported!, Please be patient when staff checks your report!`)
channel.send(embed).then(i => i.react("⏳"))
  }
}

module.exports = GuildMemberReportCommand```
````

Comment: Did you really just add random garbage to your question to fill the minimum length? Please do not use something like "need help asap" in the title

Answer (score 0):

You got to check this variable:

```
let guild = message.guild.cache.get('')
```

Just give a `console.log('guild', guild)` after this statement. Probably you might have to capture the proper field to get the channel object inside guild.

Comment: It didnt work giving me this error now ```let guild = message.guild.cache.get('649307150207942687')
                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined```

Answer (score 0):

`.find()` method takes a function. For your case, you can use arrow function. Eg: `..cache.find(ch=>ch.id==='yourid')` where `ch` would be a Channel Object in your case.